# File 'root/lib/armeabi-v7a/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, android-app-bundle

When I try to build an Android App Bundle I have this error while building the Bundle file:

***File 'root/lib/armeabi-v7a/include/opencv2/flann/sampling.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.***

Any solution please

Comment: You shouldn't be including source files (.h) in your application.

How did you include the dependency to opencv?

Comment: I include all .jar files from https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/releases.